# How can I Create a join between two sharepoint custom list using CAML Query?

Tags: caml-query

Will you please provide me help to create a join between two SharePoint lists using CAML Queries. I am using SharePoint 2010 Development Platform. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to do a formal "Join" like you would using straight SQL, it just isn't supported by straight CAML.

You can use SPQuery.Joins: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.joins(office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to getting the Join CAML query syntax is using the Linq to SharePoint to generate the proxy of the required lists. Then writing the join statements using Linq in your C# code behind.

Run the code and set up a breakpoint at that specific statement where you are writing the join. In the quick watch window, you will be able to see the join syntx in CAML.

Answer (score 0):

You should use CAML Query Builder.

Please check: http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2011/01/u2u-caml-query-builder-for-sharepoint.html

Comment: We prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article very much helpful to understand how can I create a join in caml and linq

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/01/20/sharepoint-2010-caml-list-joins.aspx