# CAML : How to Join Two List in CAML Query?

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, caml-query, caml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I Create a join between two sharepoint custom list using CAML Query?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7406/how-can-i-create-a-join-between-two-sharepoint-custom-list-using-caml-query)

I have been asked this question in interviews a lot and I am still trying to figure out what should be the best answer for it?

I read a blog somewhere which has mentioned about providing two list instance and then using the CAML for it but not sure.

Can anyone please be more specific and help me understanding the answer of above question?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This question has already been answered in this thread: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7406/how-can-i-create-a-join-between-two-sharepoint-custom-list-using-caml-query

Comment: I know, but as I said, I'm looking it to answer it in interviews.